# Determining all arithmetic multiplicative functions that are idempotent to the convolution product

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, convolution, multiplicative-function, divisor-counting-function

**Exercise.** Determine all the arithmetic multiplicative functions that are idempontent to the convolution product, i.e., determine all the functions $f$ such that, for every $a \in \Bbb N$, we have:

$$
(f * f)(n) = \sum_{d|n} f(d)f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = f(n)
$$

**My attempt (not complete resolution).**

Assuming that $n$ is square-free, we can guarantee that $\left(d,\frac{n}{d}\right) = 1$ and thus we can use the fact that $f$ is multiplicative. In this cases,  $
 f(d)f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = f(n) $ and thus the sum above is no more than $f(n) \tau(n)$, where $\tau(n)$ is the function that represents the number of divisors of $n$. Thus,

$$ 
f(n)\tau(n) = f(n) \Leftrightarrow f(n)(\tau(n)-1) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \tau(n) = 1 \vee f(n) = 0.
$$
The only $n$ for which $\tau(n) = 1$ is $n=1$ and thus the only function that verifies this is the following:

$$
  f(n) = \begin{cases}  1, \text{ if } n = 1 \\ 0, \text{ if } n>1 \end{cases} = \epsilon(n)
$$
Now we have to deal with the case where $n$ isn't square-free, i.e., $n = p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k}$ where each of the exponents $a_i$ can be superior than two. I understand that since $f(n)$ is multiplicative, we only have to study the case where $n = p^a$ and extend this result in the end. But how would one do so?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The identity for Dirichlet convolution is the Kronecker delta function $\delta_{1,n}=\delta_{n-1}=\begin{cases}  1,\ n = 1 \\ 0,\ \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ so  $\delta_{1,n} * a(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} \delta_{1,d}\ a\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=a(n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ring of arithmetic functions under Dirichlet convolution (with values in, say, $\mathbb{C}$, or more generally any integral domain) is an integral domain, so if $f^2 = f$ then $f(1 - f) = 0$ which gives $f = 0, 1$. We don't need to assume that $f$ is multiplicative.

This is easiest to see by passing to formal Dirichlet series, sending $f$ to

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{f(n)}{n^s}$$

which shows, once we write $n^{-s}$ as a product $\prod p_i^{-e_i s}$ using the prime factorization of $n$, that the ring of arithmetic functions under Dirichlet convolution, or equivalently the ring of formal Dirichlet series, is a formal power series ring in countably many variables $p^{-s}$, one for each prime; this is an integral domain.

Comment: Where the identity is the Kronecker delta function $\delta_{1,n}=\delta_{n-1}$?

Comment: @Steven: yes, that's right.